# different between ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll and ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.dll

Tags: servicestack

Recently I am working on servicestack project. When I am trying to add `open ServiceStack.ServiceInterface` in project it is showing below error.

[image]

PFB image for code.

[image]
As suggested in error, when i am trying add `open ServiceStack.Interfaces` then it is showing dll is not present.

1. please tell me why it is showing error?
2. What is different of this two DLL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ServiceStack.ServiceInterfaces` contains interfaces used by the ServiceStack webstack while `ServiceStack.Interfaces` is used by the various other ServiceStack projects (like OrmLite) as well.
ServiceStack.ServiceInterfaces depends on ServiceStack.Interfaces, which means you have to install it as well (it is a seperate nuget package)